# How to use Maven Surefire plug-in with different groups for test and integration-test?

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin, testng, surefire

I want to use **[testng](http://testng.org/)** with the [Surefire plug-in](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/) of [Maven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven). The idea is to tag some tests with a group `integrationTest` and run the plug-in twice: for goal `test` excluding the group `integrationTest` and for goal `integration-test` including the group `integrationTest` only.

I found some [material](http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=62120) for running the plug-in for both goals and that works, but the group for the second run does not work (no test is executed).

Here is the plug-in configuration in the build element of my `pom.xml`:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <excludedGroups>integrationTest</excludedGroups>
      <reportFormat>brief</reportFormat>
      <trimStackTrace>true</trimStackTrace>
      <useFile>false</useFile>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>integration-test</id>
        <phase>integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>test</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <groups>integrationTest</groups>
          <excludedGroups/>
          <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports/integration</reportsDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Any idea? `mvn integration-test` runs all unit tests as expected (excluding the group `integrationTest`) but the second test run just writes:

> Running TestSuite
>   Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.562 sec

The Result of `mvn test` is as expected, tests run and group `integrationTest` is ignored.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I got it - irritating configuration implementation!

`<excludedGroups/>` does not override `<excludedGroups>integrationTest</excludedGroups>`. You need to specify any (unknown) group instead, `<excludedGroups>none</excludedGroups>` for example.

Comment: excludedGroups does not work with TestNG 5.14.1 - use 5.14.2 instead!

Comment: With Surefire 2.18.1 and JUnit 4.10, I get the error `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (integration-test) on project example-project: Execution integration-test of
 goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load category: none`. It seems the group you override with must at least exist, even if it's not used anywhere. I do this with a `public interface SystemTest extends IntegrationTest` and exclude *that* category.

Answer (score 9):

The [Failsafe plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/index.html) is the best way to do this (it may not have been available when you posted this question). It adds an integration-test phase to the build lifecycle. It allows you to have setup and teardown activities run before and after the tests, which is useful for managing an embedded container, for example.

Comment: You might be right: Maven Central search dates the oldest maven-failsafe-plugin artifact to January 12, 2010. Since then, I think, it's become the preferred solution to the problem.